# How to Run multiple test cases at a time (in parallel) through robot framework

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, robotframework

I have a test scenario , 
in which a portal has to be used by 20 users simultaneously and the performance of the portal has to be reported. for this to happen , i need to access the portal in 20 chrome browsers simultaneously.

Is this possible through robot framework ?? If so , how ??

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is stress test, not functional test. Robot Framework is perfect for functional test, but will soon reach its limit for Stress Test. I would suggest to turn to a more appropriate tool for the Job. On my projects, I use Robot Framework for Functional tests and use [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/) for Stress Tests. It is quite easy to [record](https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Recorder) a scenario and then have the tool run it for 20 users at the same time. You will get stress-tests oriented reports, and will easily move to more complex scenario of stress tests.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in to robotframework to support parallel execution. It can be done but you'll have to do some work. For example, the simplest is to create a shell script (or batch script, or powershell script...) that simply calls robot 20 times in 20 processes, waits for them to complete, and then consolidates the logs.

When I googled on "robotframework parallel", the first hit took me to a library named [Parallel](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/proto/parallel/doc/Parallel.html), which advertises:

> Library for executing tests in parallel from inside of a robot test
>   case.

There is also [pabot](https://github.com/mkorpela/pabot), which is "A parallel executor for Robot Framework test cases." This one has been discussed in the robotframework-users group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/robotframework-users/parallel%7Csort%3adate/robotframework-users/K7Tos3XUNBE/aJrOXyAhwooJ), among other places.

However, since you mentioned using chrome, I assume these use the selenium library. There is a limit to how many browsers you can have open on a machine, and the limit is below 20. So, you'll have to either run these tests on more than one machine, or set up a [selenium grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) that these tests can leverage so they aren't all opening browser windows on the same machine.

There's a wiki page showing a possible solution using grid here: [Use Selenium GRID with Robotframework](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/wiki/UseSeleniumGRIDwithRobotFramework)